# Получаю пустой массив после JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript

собственно вот код 
html

```
<div id="sheet" class="inner" style="display: block;">
    <div>
       <input id="size1" type="text">
    </div>
    <div>
         <input id="size2" type="text">
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
$('body .frontend-setup-form #secure').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var json;
    var shirts = [];
    var shirt = [];
    $('body .frontend-setup-form #sheet input').each(function () {
        if($(this).val()!='') {
            shirt['name'] = $(this).attr('id');
            shirt['value'] = $(this).val();
            shirts.push(shirt);
        }
    });
   json={shirts:shirts}
   console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
```

получаю

```
{"shirts":[[]]}
```

хотелось бы

```
{
    "name":"patern",
    "shirt": [
        {
            "name": "size1",
            "value": "размер1"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "size2",
            "value": "размер2"
        }

    ]
}
```

Comment: Приведите [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), потому что с этим оторванным от контекста куском кода мы ничего сделать не можем *(ан нет, Grundy смог :)*

Comment: @andreymal вам html нужен ?  или что  не понятно ?

Comment: Довольно очевидно, что код завязан на html, поэтому без него, разумеется, никак

Comment: #secure там нету айди

Comment: @L.Vadim вам всю страницу выложить в том числе и ссылку на которую клик делаю ?

Comment: просто чтоб было представление что вы делаете

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ошибка в типе переменной `shirt`.

В данном случае это массив. При сериализации массива с помощью [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) на выходе будет массив с количеством элементов соответствующих `length`.

Свойство `length` - это число, большее максимального индекса.

В данном случае, максимальный индекс в массиве `0`, так как элементы в него не добавлялись.

Поэтому на выходе имеется пустой массив.

## Для решения нужно заменить массив (`[]`), на объект (`{}`)

```
var shirt = {};
```

## А также необходимо внести определение переменной `shirt` внутрь цикла.

---

Чтобы не возникало проблемы со сторонними переменными, вместо [`each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) нужно использовать [`map`](https://api.jquery.com/map/), [`filter`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) и [`get`](https://api.jquery.com/get/)(для получения результата)

```js
var shirts = $('input')
  .filter(function() {
    return this.value != ''
  })
  .map(function() {
    return {
      name: $(this).attr('id'),
      value: $(this).val()
    }
  })
  .get();
console.log(JSON.stringify(shirts));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sheet" class="inner" style="display: block;">
  <div>
    <input id="size1" type="text" value='123'>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="size2" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: пробовал делать и через объект следующим образом
`$('body .frontend-setup-form #secure').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var json;
    var shirts = [];
    var shirt = [];
    $('body .frontend-setup-form #sheet input').each(function () {
        if($(this).val()!='') {
            shirt['name'] = $(this).attr('id');
            shirt['value'] = $(this).val();
            shirts+={name:shirt['name'],value:shirt['value']}
        }
    });
   json={shirts:shirts}
   console.log(JSON.stringify(json));`
ни чего не получилось тоже

Comment: @Sergalas, откуда у тебя этот код? что за странное использование массива с оператором `+=`? где ты увидел, что я говорил, что надо менять именно эту часть? Посмотри внимательно в моей ответе, что именно я сказан нужно заменить и на что? В коде в комментарии - ты сделал непонятно что, и непонятно как это относится к моему ответу, кроме одного слова _объект_?

Comment: @Sergalas, я выделил место, в котором описано решение.

Comment: хорошо исправил на 
`if($(this).val()!='') {
                shirt={'name':$(this).attr('id')};
                shirt={'value':$(this).val()};
                shirts.push(shirt);
            }`
а почему name  не получил?

Comment: @Sergalas, ответ очевиден: просто подумай что делает твой код. Дай угадаю, раньше ты использовал php?

Comment: походу и сейчас тоже использую yii2 юзаю. Спасибо понял где туплю все получилось :)