# Вывод на консоль массива с нечисловым ключом

Tags: javascript

Почему код во фрагменте кода ниже, который должен вывести

```
[ a: 2 ]
```

выводит

```
[]
```

```js
const arr = [];
arr['a'] = 2;
console.log(arr);
```

как добиться желаемого вывода

Comment: твоя ошибка в том, что код ниже **не должен** выводить `[ a: 2 ]`. Чтобы это заработало, замени `[]` в строке `const arr = [];` на `{}`

Comment: Гм, а в хроме выводится `[a: 2]`, интересненько (о, кто-то с меты таки перенёс)

Comment: @Qwertiy [Получаю пустой массив после JSON.stringify](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/622844/186999)

Comment: @Grundy, верно, потому что json не предусматривает возможность наличия таких ключей у массивов, а так же не предусматривает sparse-массивов.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67705/discussion-on-question-by-tilin-------).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Массив является объектом и свойство ему добавить можно. Более того, приведённый тобой код действительно добавляет свойство, просто оно не отображается при выводе на консоль, поскольку вывод на консоль для массивов выводит только набор элементов массива (свойства с целыми неотрицательными int32-ключами).

Чтобы убедиться, что код работает, можно вывести непосредственно значение свойства:

```js
const arr = [];
arr['a'] = 2;
console.log(arr);
console.log(arr.a);
```

PS: А вообще, добавлять нечисловые ключи к массивам - это, обычно, плохая практика.

Comment: Но хром-то выводит именно `[a: 2]`. Grundy считает, что вопрос был про релизацию console в сниппете SO, и вопрос должен находиться на Мете

Comment: Да, вопрос был про реализацию console в сниппете.

Comment: @andreymal, ну в хроме подумали про нечисловые ключи, а в FF - нет. В любом случае ответ, что это проблема вывода, а не кода. Не вижу, где бы говорилось, что речь о снипетах. А, нет, увидел, там тег стоит.

Comment: @andreymal, а у меня хром не выводит `[a: 2]` даже есть напрямую в консоли писать

Comment: @Qwertiy а я вот не вижу/не знаю причин, почему хрому следует выводить не числовые ключи. Наверно, я сейчас отдельный вопрос создам про это)

Comment: @andreymal, потому что иначе их было бы нельзя увидеть в консоли. Я и тут могу ответить. Давай оба вопроса оставим - тут и на мете.